# How can I bind a winforms Opacity to a TrackBar (slider)

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, trackbar

I've got a winform with a `BindingSource` that has an int property named `Opacity` in its `DataSource`.  I also have a `TrackBar` on the winform that I want to use to control the `Opacity` of the winform.

I've bound the `Value` property on the `TrackBar` to the `Opacity` and that functions just fine, sliding the `TrackBar` will change the variable from `TrackBar.Minimum` (0) to `TrackBar.Maximum` (1).

I've also bound the `Opacity` property of the winform to this value, however, since the `TrackBar`'s values only go from Minimum to Maximum in +/-1 rather than +/- .1 or so (like `Opacity` does), it doesn't properly fade the winform.  Instead, 0 will turn it opaque and 1 will turn it fully visible.

**I need a way to work within the architecture described above, but get the `TrackBar` to change its value from 0 to 1 in defined increments smaller than 1.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the cleanest way to do this would be to create a `UserControl` that inherits directly from `TrackBar`, that hides the `Value`, `SmallChange`, `Minimum`, `Maximum` and `TickFrequency` properties with same-named `double` properties:

```
public partial class DoubleTrackBar : TrackBar
{
    public DoubleTrackBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int _multiplier = 100;

    [Browsable(true)]
    public new double TickFrequency
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)base.TickFrequency / _multiplier;
        }
        set
        {
            base.TickFrequency = (int)(value * _multiplier);
        }
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    public new double Minimum
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)base.Minimum / _multiplier;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Minimum = (int)(value * _multiplier);
        }
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    public new double Maximum
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)base.Maximum / _multiplier;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Maximum = (int)(value * _multiplier);
        }
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    public new double Value
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)base.Value / _multiplier;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Value = (int)(value * _multiplier);
        }
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    public new double SmallChange
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)base.SmallChange / _multiplier;
        }
        set
        {
            base.SmallChange = (int)(value * _multiplier);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That could be pretty clean! +1  I was avoiding that because for some reason I was thinking "write your own TrackBar" rather than just "extend the existing TrackBar"

Comment: Well this is sexier than my approach so I'm marking it as the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're databinding then you have a data class that has a `double OpacityForSlider` (or something similar) that you've bound the `Value` of the `TrackBar` to.

Set the sliders min and max to 0-100 and add this to your data class

```
public double OpacityForForm
{
    get { return this.OpacityForSlider / 100; } 
}
```

Now bind your winforms `Opacity` to that, rather than `OpacityForSlider`

Comment: Yah I figured out this approach right as I posted the question, though I like your approach because you really get at the meat of the question, "How do I get values I want from the `TrackBar`".  Yours is more flexible and could be re-used alot